# Why Expander binding difference datacontext of gruoping DataGrid/ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have issue that I need set difference color of `Expander`.

And the `Expander` is grouping for a `ListView`, then sometimes, group well be empty.

Now, I have two class to set groups and items. Just ref this "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33986/Empty-groups-in-WPF-ListView"

And, my class add a property of `StatusColor` and binding it.

```
class Cluster
{
    private SolidColorBrush _statusColor;
    public SolidColorBrush StatusColor
    {
        get { return _statusColor; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _statusColor, value); }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, `Header` of `Expander` in xaml like:

```
<Expander.Header>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Items[0].Cluster.StatusColor}"/>
</Expander.Header>
```

It's work when List have no any empty group. But if empty group, `Items[0]` will be null. So I want to bind `StatusColor`, it no bind `Items[0].Cluster.StatusColor`.

Why `Text` can bind `Name` of `Cluster`, but `Foreground` can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue myself.

In fact, the problem is dependence on groups setting.

Usually, I grouping by Name of `Cluster`, actually, it I always need to group by object of `Cluster`.

So, when I set `PropertyGroupDescription`:

```
PropertyGroupDescription group = new PropertyGroupDescription("Cluster.Name");
group.GroupNames.Add(cluster.Name);
```

It use a `string` to group those data. Then the `Name` of `Binding Name` mean a `string` of `Cluster.Name`, not a `object` of `Cluster`.

However, the `Binding Items[0].Cluster.Property` mean items of someone group. Then, it's a `object` and difference from a `string` of `Name`.

So, I modify group setting.

```
PropertyGroupDescription group = new PropertyGroupDescription("Cluster");
group.GroupNames.Add(cluster);
```

It's true that grouping by `object` of `Cluster`. But the xaml will be:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name.Name}" Foreground="{Binding Name.StatusColor,FallbackValue=Green}"/>
```

Now, the `Name` mean a `object` of `Cluster`, so `Text` bind `Name.Name`, the second `Name` is property of `Cluster`, and I can use `Name.StatusColor` to bind `Foreground`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property is bound to the `Name` property of the `System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewGroup` object that gets created by WPF and being set as the `DataContext` of a `GroupItem`.

`StatusColor` is a property of your custom `Cluster` object within each group. Big difference. Obviously you cannot bind to this property if there are no items in the group because then there is nothing to bind to.

Your groups have no `StatusColor` but your `Cluster` items has.

What you could do is to use the `FallbackValue` property of the `Binding` to specify the `Foreground` to use when the group is empty:

```
<Expander.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Items[0].Cluster.StatusColor,FallbackValue=Green}"/>
</Expander.Header>
```

It should be clear that an individual `Cluster` object cannot decide the colour of an empty Group though.